# Website background transparent scale. How to Fix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I complie my website via google chrome, It's transparent scale background

This Screen Image:
https://www.img.in.th/image/fyPY

How to Fix?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to add a `background-color` property to your website using CSS. You can find more information in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) article.